# api call through collectionView didSelect delegate

Tags: ios, swift, api, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal scrolling `collectionView` in my `tableView` as a list of category items cell, where i want to make an `API` call in `collectionView`'s `didSelectItemAt` delegate method and update the `self` data with the data fetched from the `API` and `reload` the `tableView` with the new data.. However, `tableView` is appending the new data to the previous ones fetched from the `API`

How can I reload the `tableView` with the new data?

-- here is my API call function:

```
 func getData(categoryKey: String, subCategoryKey: String) {
        if (page == 0) {
            data = []
            hasMore = false
        }
        guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken") else {return}
        
        DataFetcher.getData(token: token, limit: limit, skip: skip, category: categoryKey, subCategory: subCategoryKey, completion: { (response) in
            
            self.hasMore = response.hasMore!
            self.page += 1
            self.skip = response.skip
//            self.limit += self.limit
            //self.date = response.date
            self.data.append(contentsOf: response.items)
            
            if let total = response.totalCount {
                self.totalCount = total
            } else {
                self.totalCount = 0
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
```

and I am calling this call from `collectionView didSelect`  delegate like this:

```
 let item = self.type[indexPath.row]
     // item type is the property that holds parameter String values: you can imagine that it is the cell indices
    // subCategory & category is the parameter String values where I assign them upon the cell selection and pass it to the API calling func as a value
        switch item.type {
        case .Male:
            self.type[getIndex(type: .Male)].category = "Male"
            self.type[getIndex(type: .Male)].subCategory = "Male"
            
            self.category = self.type[getIndex(type: .Male)].category
            self.subCategory = self.type[getIndex(type:.Male)].subCategory
           //The Api Call func
            getData(categoryKey: self.category!, subCategoryKey: self.subCategory!)
            print(category!,subCategory!)
         case .Female:
            self.type[getIndex(type: .Female)].category = "Female"
            self.type[getIndex(type: .Female)].subCategory = "Female"
            
            self.category = self.type[getIndex(type: .Female)].category
            self.subCategory = self.type[getIndex(type:.Female)].subCategory
           
            getData(categoryKey: self.category!, subCategoryKey: self.subCategory!)
            print(category!,subCategory!)
}
```

why newly fetched data is appending to the previous one, even if i am making the api call with different parameter values as a different call?

Comment: What does `self.data.append(contentsOf: response.items)` do?

Comment: well, `self.data` is the codable structure which conatains name and price variables and should append the response items everytime tableview scrolls, untill the self.hasmore flags returns false

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all items from data array at the first line of your function getData.

```
self.data.removeAll()
```